# C/C++ Community Plugin Quality Rules shows Zero active

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops, sonar-plugin

I am using `SonarQube-6.7.7(LTS)` and C/C++ Community Plugin [`sonar-cxx-plugin-1.3.2.1853.jar`] version. Under `Quality Profiles` for C++ (Community) active rules all shows zero. Snapshot given below.

[image]

I have tried the following, However still i could see all the rules as `Inactive`.

```
Stopped the Sonarqube service
Deleted the $SONAR_HOME/data/es5 folder
started the service
```

Also tried with `sonar-cxx-plugin-1.3.1.1807.jar` plugin as well but still same problem. Even i can't find the option to active them manually as well. Would be grateful for any advice to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rules are active in this version of `sonar-cxx-plugin-1.2.2.1653.jar`. Here working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am using 8.4 version and c, c++ plugins of 1.3.2 . Sonar way default quality profile showing zero active rules.  Can I have solution from you . Eventhough showing zero rules active it giving the output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with `sonar-cxx-plugin-1.2.2.1653.jar`